# How to draw rows with consistent depths when dealing with unique shapes?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, sketch-app

We're trying to figure out how to draw a series of rows that have consistent depths with different types of shapes. Ie sometimes there are round parts, or shapes get wider at points, etc. The closest example of what we're trying to do is seat maps like this:
[image]

We're currently using Sketch to draw our shapes. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The Illustrator `Blend Tool` is definitely a great way to go for stuff like this. It morphs one shape into another, using a set amount of steps. That would let you create a path for the outer edge, another for the inner edge, and you could create the rows in an accurate, dynamic way.

[image: Illustrator blend tool]

Adobe’s help: [About blended objects](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/blending-objects.html)

If you need to create real objects of the in-between steps, `Object` → `Expand` can be used.

Comment: @SeanJohnson My pleasure. Oh, also worth noting that I used Object → Path → Add Anchor Points to add more steps to the smooth curve, then I used Object → Path → Simplify to make it straight line segments. If your art needs to be a lot like your example, those might help.